# jQuery context is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JQuery and this error is beyond me. I upgraded from JQuery 1.2 to 1.11 and am now getting "context is undefined" errors. I read that using createElement may be the cause of this. In the portion of the code that has stopped working after the upgrade, I have `$(document.createElement('tr'))`.

Is there another way to write this so that these errors will stop? I have tried: `$("tr")...` but the element is no longer where it needs to be on the page.

How do I resolve this?

**EDIT:**

```
  $myElement =
    $(document.createElement('tr'))
      .addClass('jqgrow')
      .attr('_boggy_call', this)
      .click( function(  )
        {
          boggy.editCall($this);
        })
      .append
        (
          $(document.createElement('td')).text($myProperties.CallNo)
        )
      .append
        (
          $(document.createElement('td')).text($myProperties.ClientAddress)
        )
      .append
        (
          $(document.createElement('td'))
            .text
              (
                boggy.UtilityValues.CallTypes[$myProperties.CodeId]
              )
        )
      .append
        (
          $(document.createElement('td'))
            .text
              (
                boggy.UtilityValues.Dispositions[$myProperties.DispoId]
              )
        )
      .appendTo('#openAir-content tbody')
```

Comment: That's a big jump in versions. Check out the jQuery migrate plugin created by the jQuery team to help with this transition. Also, post your code in your question.

Comment: Thanks j, I will look at that. Could it be possible that it will resolve this for me?

Comment: Anything's possible. But you'd improve your odds with it, and by posting your code in your question :)

Comment: Neta, I didn't develop the JavaScript in this app, a friend did, so I can only guess that there wasn't support in 1.2 for a `$('tr')` declaration. I could be wrong tho

Comment: @NetaMeta it should be `$("<tr/>")` - `$("tr")` is a request to *find* all the `<tr>` elements on the page.

Comment: `$("tr")`  will search for all `<tr>` elements that are currently in the DOM. The equivalent to `$(document.createElement('tr'))`  would be `$('<tr>')`, but this should actually not be the reason for the error message.

Comment: Also that particular line of code is not the problem. It's a weird thing to do, but it will work. Use a non-minified version of jQuery and find out via your developer tools exactly where the error is happening.

Comment: I just used migrate and I am still getting `TypeError: context is undefined`

Comment: @Pointy, I have already switched out the minified library for the dev library. The line on 1.11 of the dev library that is complaining is around 1460, function `Sizzle.contains = function( context, elem )`

Comment: @Pointy, I hate to ask, but can you please tell me how to do that? I'm using Firebug but have no idea how to debug this. Sorry, I'm not a JS dev. Or, maybe you can point me to where I need to look and I can report back with what I find.

Comment: OK well set a breakpoint there and reload the page. That will give you a stack trace. Look up the stack to the point in your code that makes a jQuery request, and that will almost certainly be where the root of the problem lies. jQuery version 1.2 is extremely old, and many APIs have been deprecated since then. jQuery (like most libraries) has very little "helpful" error detection code in it.

Comment: Post more code, hard to troubleshoot what can't be seen

Comment: OK, posting the entire thing up top

Comment: In Chrome Developer Toolbar, you have to select the tab _Sources_  and on the right side there is a _pause_  symbol (tooltip is _Pause on exception_), check that one (it will become blue)  and reload the page. The debugger will now break for every error. Using the Call Stack you can see the origin of the error.  You can see more details at [Debugging JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging)

Comment: @t.niese, thanks. I just now figured out how to set the breakpoints. I put a breakpoint at the place that I believe the error is happening but I have no idea how to even interpret what it's showing me.

Comment: @NaN I think the problem is with `$myProperties` object, I tested your code by replacing `$myProperties` occurrences with some text and the the table was populated correctly without any errors under `firefox 34`, here's [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/17s98o1z).So am I missing something?

Comment: @FaresM, you're right, it is being populated and I am also on FF 34. Can you tell me how I can pinpoint where these errors are coming from? I continually get this "context is undefined" error and thought it was because if the `$(document)` declarations. This is obviously not the issue as you have proven.

Comment: As pointed by @t.niese, use `firebug` extension and inspect its javascript console to see the error when loading the page, so you can click the error to expand its `stacktrace` to get the right line of your code that causing this error.

Comment: @FaresM, I have been watching the console and I have noticed that when I get these errors that it is always after an AJAX call. Should I be looking at the AJAX call itself as a possible source of the error?

Comment: @NaN Then debug your `ajax` request response.

Comment: Thanks Fares. I'll see what I can find